# How to select C++ value if any radio button not selected using selenium

Tags: selenium

How to select C++ value if any radio button not selected

```
<form name="testform" action="" method="POST">  
 <div align="center">
  <br>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" value="Java">Java  
   <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" value="C++">C++   
   <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" value="Python">Python
  </br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can induce a simple check on the WebElement to check if it is selected or not and if not selected click on it to select as follows:

```
    WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='option-2']"));
    if(!element.isSelected())
    {
        element.click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :-

```
webElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='option-2']"));

element.getAttribute("value")) 

or

element.getText();
```

Comment: scenario is i need to check first whether the radio button is selected if it is not selected then i need to select value c++